# Ignore a mdx file (from build) in contentlayer based on field

Tags: next.js, mdxjs, contentlayer

I'm building a blog using Next.js and contenlayer. I have the following code which display a list of blog posts based on a condition in the "All Posts" page. But this just filters the list in the "All Posts" page - that means if the user manually types a url to a blogpost which exists but doesn't meet the condition, they will still be able to view it.

How can I avoid that?

```js
import { allPosts, type Post } from "contentlayer/generated";

const posts = allPosts.filter((post: Post) => post.published);
```

For Example, in the above code, the `posts` variable just removes the posts where the field `published: false`, but if I have a page called `sample-page` with field `published: false` and manually go to a url `http://localhost:3000/blog/sample-post` - the page still gets rendered.

How can I get a 404 in this case?